# Is today a real weekday?

Tags: code-golf, date

Feb. 6 was a real weekday. Because it lies in the 6th week of the year.
So a real weekday is a day with a a day number that equals the week number.

But not all country have the same counting of weeks. in Germany a week starts with Monday and ends on Saturday in the US they start on Sunday.

Write a program that checks a given date (the format your program likes the best) and a weekstart ('S' or 'M') whether it is a real weekday.

Too simplify things a bit we assume January 1st is always a real weekday because it is in the first week. In Germany it is the last day of week 52)

Some examples of real weekday for a start on Monday:

```
 2017-01-01
 2017-02-07
 2017-04-17
```

Some examples of real weekday for a start on Sunday:

```
2017-01-01
2017-02-06
2017-04-16
```

Example:

```
2017-04-16 S Output: YES
20170416M Output: 0
```

How you enter the Date does not matter, as long as it is human readable. The start day can be given by M or S or 1 or 0.
the Output is a printed boolean Yes, not or Y,N or 0,1

Shortest code wins!

Its my first question I put on this forum, so I'd be happy to hear some comments.

Comment: It's not clear. Can our program use *either* Sunday or Monday start days or does it have to accept a second input and handle both

Comment: Could you provide more clear examples of input and output?

Comment: @Suever, seems like no, as he writes "checks a given date ... **and** a weekstart".

Comment: Could you confirm "the first week of 2017 for a start of "Monday" is just one day long, having the second week start on Monday the 2nd"?

Comment: @Jonathan: yes that is true!

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG! I think this is an interesting enough question, there are just a few points that need to be made a bit more clear, so I've voted to close this question as unclear in the meantime. In the future, I strongly recommend making use of the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can post challenges and get meaningful feedback before posting them to main. Welcome to the site!

Comment: I added a bit of explanation for  the valid input.

Comment: "_Feb. 6 was a real weekday. Because it lies in the 6th week of the year. So a real weekday is a day with a day number that equals the week number._" How I interpret this is: `real_weekday: week_of_year == day_of_month`. But what does this have to do with the day of the week? A year is just 52 weeks, and the `week_of_year` is based on that like an index. So it shouldn't matter whether it's Monday, Sunday, or Wednesday, unless I'm misinterpreting something here.. :S

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the week starts on sunday/monday, for example 2016-01-01 was a friday , so it was in the 53th week of 2015, the 1st week of 2016 started on 03(or 04) of january

Comment: So in Germany are weeks only 6 days long?

Comment: @Rod - that is not quite the case, see my question, above. The *second* week of 2016 started on the 3rd/4th

Comment: So this is just false for anything after the 31st week in the year?

Comment: @carusocumputing thats true; after the 31st week ther is nor real week day

Comment: @Kevin,@LLiw Week are complicated. I tried to simplify the question for the two types I know. Weeks starting on Sunday and Weeks starting on Mondays (ending on Sundays) and that January the 1st is always on the first week of the new year.
In Germany (and in Europe) it's a bit more complicated. The first week of the year is the week containing Jan 4th. So Dec 31st can be on Week 1 and Jan 1st can be on week 52, (Sometimes even week 53 like in 2005 and 2010). BTW: Its not a funny oddity its international standard.(ISO 8601).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## MATLAB, 53 bytes

```
d=datetime(input(''));week(d-(input('')=='M'))==d.Day
```

This answer accepts the first input as a string `'2017-02-06'` and the second input as a string (either `'S'` or `'M'`).

[image]

It constructs a `datetime` object from the first input and saves it in `d`. We then compute the week number (but first we subtract 1 day from the date if the second input is an `'M'` since `week` uses Sundays by default) and then we compare this week number to the day of the `datetime` object to yield a boolean.

Comment: Great! But where do you specify whether the week starts with Sunday or Monday?

Comment: @JoachimWeiß Fixed.